# Extracting the XML structure using Java

Tags: java, xml, structure

Is there a Java library that lets you extract / create an XML document so what you end up with is the "barebone" XML structure of the document.

Example

```
<result>
    <rowset name="kills" key="killID" columns="killID,solarSystemID,killTime,moonID">
      <row killID="54933226" solarSystemID="31001222" killTime="2016-07-03 22:29:19" moonID="0">
        <victim characterID="93811169" characterName="Madcat326" corporationID="98008818" corporationName="Haight Industries LLC" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="63039" shipTypeID="17918" x="59788513854.179" y="-13687850177.3741" z="157817245029.115" />
        <rowset name="attackers" columns="characterID,characterName,corporationID,corporationName,allianceID,allianceName,factionID,factionName,securityStatus,damageDone,finalBlow,weaponTypeID,shipTypeID">
          <row characterID="91316135" characterName="Celeo Servasse" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-1.0646369409683" damageDone="7825" finalBlow="1" weaponTypeID="3520" shipTypeID="12003" />
          <row characterID="95273329" characterName="Mupoc Kashuken" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-0.2" damageDone="16656" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="31882" shipTypeID="12023" />
        </rowset>
        <rowset name="items" columns="typeID,flag,qtyDropped,qtyDestroyed,singleton">
          <row typeID="394" flag="20" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="24427" flag="32" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="2446" flag="87" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="28209" flag="87" qtyDropped="2" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
        </rowset>
      </row>
    </rowset>
</result>
```

Would be recreated to something like

```
<result>
    <rowset name="kills" key="killID" columns="killID,solarSystemID,killTime,moonID">
      <row killID="54933226" solarSystemID="31001222" killTime="2016-07-03 22:29:19" moonID="0">
        <victim characterID="93811169" characterName="Madcat326" corporationID="98008818" corporationName="Haight Industries LLC" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="63039" shipTypeID="17918" x="59788513854.179" y="-13687850177.3741" z="157817245029.115" />
        <rowset name="attackers" columns="characterID,characterName,corporationID,corporationName,allianceID,allianceName,factionID,factionName,securityStatus,damageDone,finalBlow,weaponTypeID,shipTypeID">
          <row characterID="91316135" characterName="Celeo Servasse" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-1.0646369409683" damageDone="7825" finalBlow="1" weaponTypeID="3520" shipTypeID="12003" />
        </rowset>
        <rowset name="items" columns="typeID,flag,qtyDropped,qtyDestroyed,singleton">
          <row typeID="394" flag="20" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
        </rowset>
      </row>
    </rowset>
</result>
```

Or how can I extract / create the structure of an XML document?

If this process is called something else, please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate a schema?

Comment: That does not sound entirely incorrect, what i would really like is to be able to take an XML document and get the structure of how its build.

Answer (score 0):

To get a useful answer, you should explain what you expect to be able to do with the result.

You can extract the structure in XSD format with online tools like http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html or http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html, is that what you are looking for ?

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="result">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="rowset">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="row">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="victim">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="characterID"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="characterName"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="corporationID"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="corporationName"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="allianceID"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="allianceName"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="factionID"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="factionName"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="damageTaken"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="shipTypeID"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="x"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="y"/>
                            <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="z"/>
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="rowset" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="row" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="characterID" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="characterName" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="corporationID" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="corporationName" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="allianceID" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="allianceName" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="factionID" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="factionName" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="securityStatus" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="damageDone" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="finalBlow" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="weaponTypeID" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="shipTypeID" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="typeID" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="flag" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="qtyDropped" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="qtyDestroyed" use="optional"/>
                                  <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="singleton" use="optional"/>
                                </xs:extension>
                              </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="columns" use="optional"/>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="killID"/>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="solarSystemID"/>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="killTime"/>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="moonID"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="key"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="columns"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hi Tristan, thanks for your reply! I dont plan to use the result / output for anything besides being able to see the document structure without redundant data such as a row, that has no children inside a parent ect. I have tried to show this in the above post / topic.

Comment: Use an XML Editor or XML Viewer in your Browser?

Comment: Yeah, as suggested by @jschnasse, you can just fold levels which contain multiple elements in any XML editor like a browser.

Comment: That could be one approach, but it becomes quite time consuming and un-handy when you have very large documents or several documents. That in turn also changes structure over time due to updates. Context, the project that lead me to this question is creating a Java application that can parse and extract data from EVE Online XML API, resource https://eveonline-third-party-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/xmlapi/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Below XSLT transformation format might help removing the duplicate child row elements. You can run this transformer from java code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/result">
        <result>
        <rowset>
        <xsl:copy-of select="rowset/@*"/>    
        <row>
         <xsl:copy-of select="rowset/row/@*"/>    
       <victim>
          <xsl:copy-of select="rowset/row/victim/@*"/>    
       </victim>        
       <rowset>       
            <xsl:copy-of select="rowset/row/rowset[@name='attackers']/@*"/> 
            <row>
            <xsl:copy-of select="rowset/row/rowset[@name='attackers']/row[1]/@*"/>
            </row>
       </rowset>
          <rowset>       
            <xsl:copy-of select="rowset/row/rowset[@name='items']/@*"/> 
            <row>
            <xsl:copy-of select="rowset/row/rowset[@name='items']/row[1]/@*"/>
            </row>
       </rowset>
       </row>
      </rowset>
        </result>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```